# Idioms for fake sadness other than crocodile tears?

Tags: idioms

Is there another saying/idiom similar to crocodile tears?

Comment: Yes. How do you want to use it? For example *Academy Award performance* is one that refers to someone who over-dramatises their emotions.  Eg.  "Mother, what will I wear? I don't have an evening dress!" And then comes Mary's Academy Award performance. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ryZ9AAAAMAAJ&q=%22academy+award+performance%22&dq=%22academy+award+performance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIkKKzh8L6yAIVwtQaCh1kLwYK

Comment: As chasly from UK said, please tell us more details about how you would like to use this term.

Answer (score 4):

One expression is: "[turning on the waterworks](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-on-the-waterworks)."

Answer (score 0):

**Pretended compassion** may fit.

> "Compassion" is a feeling of deep sympathy and sorrow for another who
> is stricken by misfortune, accompanied by a strong desire to alleviate
> the suffering.
>
> "Pretended" means feigned, insincerely or falsely professed.
>
> Example: *From the very beginning of their campaigns to get laws
> passed, all their pretended compassion for the poor suffering victims,
> and their intolerable pain, was nothing but a scam*.

Answer (score 0):

You may like [***lugubrious***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lugubrious)

Defined in Merriam Webster as:

> full of sadness or sorrow : very sad especially in an exaggerated or insincere way

And from the GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English ( via [Wordnik](https://wordnik.com/words/lugubrious)):

> Mournful; indicating sorrow, often ridiculously or feignedly; doleful; woful; pitiable.

Answer (score 0):

***phony-baloney***

*Dictionary.com* and the *Urban Dictionary* define phony-baloney respectively as "nonsense" and "lie(s) and to an extent bullshit."

Whereas crocodile tears unambiguously refers to fake sympathy, phony-baloney (p-b) has a broader usage, for example: "Don't give me any phony-baloney about how the check was lost in the mail."  But with the context specified, p-b can substitute for crocodile tears.

Sentence: "She said she was so, so sorry that I had to drop out, but it was all phony-baloney; she didn't give a rats a__."

For an extended discussion of the phrase, see [What is the source of the phrase "phony baloney"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203937/what-is-the-source-of-the-phrase-phony-baloney)  This shows up prominently on a Google search for p-b.

Answer (score 0):

*While rubbing your thumb and index finger together* say:

> You: "You know what this is?"
>
> Victim: "No. What?"
>
> You: "It's the world's smallest violin playing just for you."

#### Explanation

Violin music is often the musical score accompanying sad scenes in movies when the audience is supposed to feel sadness or sorrow for the characters.

#### Example

[Here is an example in full context from the film Resevoir Dogs by Quintin Tarantino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TPMEoM-cjc&t=1m55s).

(Link is already queued to proper time spot.)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TPMEoM-cjc&t=1m55s